# Printing string in reverse is not reverse

Tags: java

Trying to reverse the string 'never odd or even' as it's a palindrome (I want to see if a string is one). Some strings such as 'racecar' work fine, but the latter produces a weird result.

```
Scanner inp = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("In:");
String s = inp.nextLine();

for (int i = s.length() - 1; i>=0; i--) {
  System.out.print(s.charAt(i));
}
```

Inputting 'never odd or even' outputs 'neve ro ddo reven'.

Why is that?
I'm not going to use StringBuilder since we have not learnt that. Has to be in a for loop.

Comment: "Inputting 'never odd or even' outputs 'neve ro ddo reven'." Because that's what the reverse of the other string is! That string is only a palindrome if you don't count the spaces!

Comment: “neve ro ddo reven“ reads “never odd or even” backwards. The only thing weird is the spaces.

Comment: What output you are expecting ?edit and write it on  your post

Comment: A palindrome is a word, number, phrase, or other sequence of characters which **reads** the same backward as forward. As definition explain it, there is only reading same, not writing. If you want same writing, you should count character of each word(or position of each space), then redo spaces in reversed string.

Comment: Format your input with `String formatStr = s.replaceAll("\\s+","")`. Then compare `formatStr` with your output. **Note:** This will align with your requirement but not with standard palindrome definition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't print the spaces in your original string:

```
Scanner inp = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("In:");
String s = inp.nextLine();

for (int i = s.length() - 1; i>=0; i--) {
   if (s.charAt() != ' ') {System.out.print(s.charAt(i));}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because a space is still a character. You're printing every character in that string, including the spaces, in reverse.

This is exactly the behaviour you'd expect.

Answer (score 0):

```
       Scanner inp = new Scanner(System.in);
       System.out.print("In:");
       String s = inp.nextLine();
         for (int i = s.length() - 1; i>=0; i--) {
            if(s.charAt(i)==' ') {
                continue;
            }
            else {
                System.out.print(s.charAt(i));
            }
        }
```

Try the Above code